# Bevel not uniform, despite applying transforms

Tags: bevel

When using the Ctrl + B command, my bevels come out uneven for reasons I don't have the experience to troubleshoot. I have already applied all transforms on my object. My geometry is entirely manifold and the areas that I'm trying to bevel are literally just 90 degree corners, like on a cube. Pretty frustrating. [image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't crop the images so tight, the information you cropped on the left (the settings used to bevel) would help others get you an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how the "Percent" bevel mode works. Change it to one of the other modes, such as "Offset":
[image: Bevel with percent mode]
[image: Bevel with offset mode]